# How do I make this change in my VIM config?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, vi

```
Control + Right = end
Control + Left = home
Control + down = page down
COntrol + up = page up
```

I want these to work, regardless of what mode (insert or not) I'm in.

What do I put into my .vimrc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:map <C-Right> <End>
:map <C-Left> <Home>
:map <C-Down> <PageDown>
:map <C-Up> <PageUp>
```

should do it.

Or

```
:imap <C-Right> <End>
:imap <C-Left> <Home>
:imap <C-Down> <PageDown>
:imap <C-Up> <PageUp>

:nmap <C-Right> <End>
:nmap <C-Left> <Home>
:nmap <C-Down> <PageDown>
:nmap <C-Up> <PageUp>
```

Comment: Hi, the page up and page down work. But for some reason, the left and right do not go to home and end? Instead, it moves my cursor one char to the right when I do CTRL + right

Comment: @alex - are you using vim or gvim ? Do you have anything in your vimrc regarding movement of Home and End ?